# Incrementing integer from other script

Tags: python

Im trying to understand how I can access and increment an integer that resides inside another script. My hierachy is like this:

```
- TestDirectory
-- foo.py
-- bar.py
```

Example:

***foo.py***

```
import TestDirectory.bar as bar
def main():
    testCounter = 0
    bar.increment()
    print(testCounter)

main()
```

***bar.py***

```
import TestDirectory.foo as foo
def increment():
    foo.main().testCounter += 1
```

I expected my print to return 1 but it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'TestDirectory' has no attribute 'bar'
```

Can anyone explain or solve my problem?

Comment: This will not work anyway. But the problem you face is cyclic imports I think.

Comment: Apart from the issue with cyclic imports, I am unable to reproduce this error. I get an `ImportError: No module named 'TestDirectory'`when I try to run it from outside `TestDirectory`.

Comment: But do you have an idea how to approach such a problem?

Comment: Can't you simply pass `testCounter` as an argument to `increment()` ?

Comment: So if I were to remove the import of bar inside the foo script. How would one increment the integer from the bar script?

Comment: You can pass the integer to the `script` as a parameter and update with the return value.

Comment: I will try and test it

Comment: I have added an answer to help you with this

Comment: If they're both in TestDirectory then just `import bar as bar` will make the import work. Or maybe `from TestDirectory import bar as bar` Not sure about the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my solution to help anyone else in need!

Hierachy is like this (Even though it should not matter):

```
- Folder1
-- bar.py
- Folder2
-- foo.py
```

**Solution:**

***foo.py***

```
from Folder1 import bar
def main():
    bar.increment()
    print(bar.counter)

main()
```

***bar.py***

```
counter = 0
def increment():
    global counter
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I am unable to reproduce your error(and it doesn't matter), it seems you are getting messed up in cyclic imports here.

A simple way to bypass cyclic issues in your case is as follows:

- In `bar.py`, modify the behaviour of `increment` function to take an `int` as input parameter and return after updating it.
- In `foo.py`, update `main` to send `testCounter` as an argument and catch its return value.
- Rectify the import statement in `foo.py` (depending on your convention) while removing the cyclic import in `bar.py`.

Here is the minimalistic code changes I have made to sort this issue.
P.S: Running from inside the `TestDirectory` folder.

**foo.py**

```
import bar

def main():
    testCounter = 0
    testCounter = bar.increment(testCounter)
    print(testCounter)

main()
```

**bar.py**

```
def increment(testCounter):
    testCounter += 1
    return testCounter
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues with your code:

1. Variables in methods are local to the method, you can't access them from outside the function, forget about outside the script(i.e. module)
2. To import another module in the same folder, just use the name of the script itself
3. Since you want to access `foo` from `bar` and `bar` from `foo`, you end up with a cyclic import which can be avoided with local imports

Here's a solution to your problem, but chances are, you'll do better with a design change instead of what I"m offering:

foo.py

```
import bar

testCounter=0

if __name__=="__main__":
    bar.incrementTestCounter()
    print bar.getTestCounterValue()
```

bar.py

```
def incrementTestCounter():
    import foo
    foo.testCounter=foo.testCounter+1

def getTestCounterValue():
    import foo
    return foo.testCounter
```